# Displaying default image if there is no image on server in Android

Tags: java, android, json, image, android-volley

I am learning Android by working through some tutorials. I am currently working on [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/) tutorial from androidhive. The goal of this tutorial is to display a list of movies and display year, genre, image... So now I have a question, what happens when there is no image on the server.

```
movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image"));
```

XML:

```
<com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
    android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp" />
```

How would I display a default image (for example from drawable) if the image does not exist on the server?

Comment: Include a sample json that the server returns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a default background to the networkImageView in xml :

```
<com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
    android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:background:"@drawable/default_image"
    ... />
```

and check if is string null or empty

```
if (obj.getString("image") != null && !obj.getString("image").isEmpty()) {
     movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image"));
}
```

and if you want to set it programatically just use else :

```
else {
   movie.setDefaultImageResId(R.drawable.default);
   movie.setErrorImageResId(R.drawable.error);
}
```

Comment: When I try the second approach i get the following errors: `cannot resolve method setDefaultImageResId(?)` and `cannot resolve method setErrorImageResId(?)` (_I am creating list in a fragment so that might be the reason_).

Answer (score 2):

Best way to load image from server is to use Picasso

[picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso/)

An image loading and caching library for Android focused on smooth scrolling
and it will take you just one line to do what you want.

```
Picasso.with(context)
    .load(url)
    .placeholder(R.drawable.user_placeholder)
    .error(R.drawable.user_placeholder_error)
    .into(imageView);
it's easier and cleaner.
```

Comment: @Rahul Vats Thank you for your answer. I am a beginner so this time I will use the user6749691's answer, it worked for this example, but next time I will probably use picasso :)